# How to build a dylib from several .o in Mac OS X using gcc

Tags: macos, gcc, shared-libraries, dylib

I have several .o files and want to bundle them in a .dylib, how can I do that it Mac OS X using gcc? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace *.o -o something.dylib`

Comment: Note to anyone reading this in later years: The -flat_namespace option is no longer necessary. It was a compatibility hack introduced around OS 10.4 to make libraries built with 10.4+ tools to still work with pre-10.4 systems. On later systems, it can cause linking problems and should not be used.