# Generate .dylib by .a

Tags: lua

I installed Lua 5.2 in my mac that's is lion, but the installation generated one archive .a in /usr/local/lib, but I need one .dylib.

I need generate a dynamic library by static library, how can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a dylib? Anyway, you can download one from [LuaBinaries](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Comment: I'm working with a program that needs a dynamic, the other libraries are dynamic to. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The recipe at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532589/how-to-build-a-dylib-from-several-o-in-mac-os-x-using-gcc worked for me. Just remove `lua.o` and `luac.o` from the list of object files.